# Definitive method to have a UIImageView with rounded corners in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, cornerradius

I've been a long time trying to find an acceptable method to add rounded corners to a `UIImageView` that is added as a subview in a `UITableViewCell` without impacting the scrolling performance of the `UITableView`. I'm referring to adjusting the `CALayer's` `cornerRadius` property which seriously impacts the scrolling performance (used in conjunction with `MasksToBounds`).

I'm guessing a viable method is to dive into the `UIImage` itself and mess about with the actual image - but again, yet to find an acceptable method.

So, if you have a clean method to present rounded corners in a scrollable `UITableView` whilst maintaining perfect scrolling performance i'd love to hear from you. Thanks for any help you guys can offer.

Comment: Didnt know that setting cornerRadius causes performance issues. Try with raw3d's suggestion as below. Looks like a good suggestion to me.

Comment: simply setting a corner radius should not make your app lag. iPhone's GPU is most likely able to calculate a few square roots in a second...

Comment: There's plenty of documentation online from many users that using a combination of cornerRadius and MasksToBounds in a TableView of 100+ cell does indeed cause performance issues. Setting the cornerRadius to a UIView (or even a TableView itself) of course does not cause issues, it's when it's used in a UITableViewCell; thus constantly drawing the layer when the cell enters the viewable area is when it causes issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a UIButton of type "Round Rect" and can set State config to "Disabled"  and add a image to the button..

or import QuartzCore.framework and use

```
self.imageView.layer.frame = CGRectInset(self.imageView.layer.frame, 20, 20);
```

instead of 20,20 specify your corner radius

Comment: Hmm, isn't very customizable though. Assuming you are using the default rounded rect corner radius to handle the corners? Seems a pretty restrictive method.

Answer (score 0):

iOS Stock Application is uses round corners. To accomplish this effect, the app has small rounded corners image placed on each corner of app. This technique are quick to draw and implement. Check page 134 in this book: [Pro iOS5](http://books.google.pl/books?id=ydVnKoplt1cC&pg=PA127&lpg=PA127&dq=pro%20ios5%20%22color%20blended%20layers%22&source=bl&ots=pyrsvqSjlz&sig=tZt_N1-rrQiL3SAt6qfrDr9uA3o&hl=pl&sa=X&ei=kb-qUPaqNNGAhQesx4DgDg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=pro%20ios5%20%22color%20blended%20layers%22&f=false)

Comment: This method is only viable if the UIImageView in question is a static background image. My use will be for feature's such as Facebook profile pictures where placing rounded corners on top of the image is not feasible. For what it's worth, i find this method pretty lazy and i'm a little shocked developers at Apple have used this technique. I know it's for performance reasons, but still.